# MVC 3 Project Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I´m trying to deploy an MVC 3 project to my server runing IIS 7.

I tried creating a package with VS2010.  The resulting zip-file I moved to the server and imported this to the IIS7.  This is going well so far.  I can also open the loginpage in the browser, but when logging-in (Database query for checking login data ) there comes a message "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request."

How do I have to deploy?  Are there other ways?  I manage the database connection via a dll.  I also tried to connect to localhost but this didn´t work either.

Thanks

Comment: Are you logging? If so what errors do you see?  Did you check the Event Viewer on the server to see if it recorded any errors?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.iwantmymvc.com/2011-03-23-bin-deploy-aspnet-mvc-3-visual-studio